How to configure VSCode to unit test with MSTest?
I am trying to find the correct configuration steps for MSTest in VSCode.
Platform: Ubuntu
VSCode: 1.95.3
C# Dev Kit: 1.15.2 (pre)

I have two MSTest project below: Codificer.Testing & ToolKit

How do I configure workspace settings for these test projects?

follow the ms tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/testing-library-with-visual-studio-code and then adept it to your prijecrt

@nbk: That's great, except that nothing. In that tutorial talks about workspace settings and using the test Explorer.

That doesn't help me with this question.

sorry that was for the other thread

is there a test explorer extension for MSTest

yes ... there is. But C# Dev Kit is supposed to be all inclusive now. I didn't want to add an extension that duplicates a function already in VSCode. What I've discovered is that the default Test Explorer may be broken. I switched to the Dev Kit 1.15.2 pre-release, but to no avail.
